# Efficient algorithm to find All paths between two nodes in less time

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Hi I am searching for all possible paths in directed graph has **cycles** in it. 
But I am looking for paths which will not have repeated nodes in it.
I have modified BFS and could able to find paths also, but since graph has **more than 1000**  nodes its running for longer time to extracts all paths.
~~: In graph there are some nodes which **has number of clones present** in it.

Can you please help me to find efficient algorithm which can find all paths between two nodes in short duration.

Comment: There are infinite number between two nodes that has cycle between them, and there are exponential number of simple paths. Unless you have some very specific graph, finding ALL paths between nodes for 1k nodes graph is really infeasible.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid what you are asking for is impossible.

> But I am looking for paths which will not have repeated nodes in it

This is called "simple paths" There are exponential number of those.

For example, let's imagine we have a graph with 50 vertices, and there is an edge between every pair. There are 49!~=6*10^62  simple paths between `u` and `v`. [**This is more than the number of atoms on earth**](http://education.jlab.org/qa/mathatom_05.html).

If you have much smaller graphs, you can do it with a variation of [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), that maintains a `visited` set for nodes in the current path.

Comment: I implemented a variation of DFS to find all simple paths between two points. and it is slow when graph has more nodes, but in my graph, each nodes has 3-4 edges, so in this case, is there possibility for faster algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless you have a specific graph with predefined connections. Even if we could generate (1000-1)! number of paths and store it in some imaginary device, searching for an appropriate path in such a database (or interpreting such large data) would again account for a very high time complexity.

If one wants to find a path between two points with specific conditions (or properties) there are many algorithms for such a design, where one does not have to find all the possible paths to obtain the end result (even in cases where the most optimal path between two points cannot be searched within polynomial time there are approximation algorithms that might help to some extent).

This problem is more like the [longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Approximation) which is NP hard if its not a directed a-cyclic graph.